# Regex to match the ratings used by the Australian Classification Board

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I was trying to make a list by scraping HTML earlier and I realised the same pattern happened occurred twice with the data I wanted appearing first shortly followed by the same data except with one of the Australian Classification letters as a string.

How would one go about matching only the classification ratings and how would one match the desired pattern while skipping the undesired one?

Example:
`<a href="url" title="Name">Name</a>` and a similar one except `<a href="url" title="Name">Rating</a>`. Aiming to match either the `Name` or the entirety of the first example.

Current attempts include:

- PCRE - `<a href=\".*\" title=\"(.*)\">\g1<\/a>` which didn't work
- `<a href=\".*\" title=\".*\">.*<\/a>` to match them all. This one ended up matching both the desired pattern as well as the pattern including the Rating.
- `<a href=\".*\" title=\".*\">[(?!(MA15\+)(PG)(G)(M)(R)]+.*<\/a>` negative lookahead to match only the right beginning and hopefully avoid matching the Rating.

Note: [Australia Classification Board](https://www.classification.gov.au/) has multiple ratings including: CTC, G, PG, M, MA15+, R18+ and X18+; all used (almost) exclusively in upper case.

Note (again): The type of regex doesn't really matter.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to match. Please show example inputs with their expected matches. Also, please show what you've tried and explain how it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `<a href="[^"]*" title="(?!(?:CTC|P?G|M(?:A15\+)?|[RX]18\+)")([^"]*)">\g1</a>` https://regex101.com/r/6vLOM1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the last pattern that you tried:

If you place the values after each other like `(MA15\+)(PG)(G)(M)(R)` that means it will match a string `MA15+PGGMR`

If you place it between square brackets like `[(?!(MA15\+)(PG)(G)(M)(R)]` it is a character class matching one of the listed characters.

---

You could use a negative lookahead listing the alternatives using a `|` to denote an alternation.

```
<a href="[^"]*" title="(?!(?:CTC|P?G|M(?:A15\+)?|[RX]18\+)")([^"]*)">\g1</a>
```

**Explanation**

- `<a href="[^"]*" title="` The start of the string, using a negated character class `[^` to match any char except `"`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, asset what is directly to the right is not

  - `(?:CTC|P?G|M(?:A15\+)?|[RX]18\+)"` Match one of the alternatives followed by the closing `"`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `([^"]*)">` Capture **group 1**, match 0+ any char except `'` followed by matching a `>`
- `\g1` Match the same text as matched by group 1
- `</a>` Match the ending part of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6vLOM1/1)